# SQL Query in PHP script doesnt fill table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In PHP script I parsed some .csv file and trying to execute on a few ways and this is a closest I can get. When I run query manually in database everything is o.k but when I go through the the script    I just got `New record created successfully` and the table stays empty except ID which count how many inserts I got.

o.k that's cool optimization but I still don't getting the data. Yap the $dataPacked is clear below is my whole script can you pls gave some suggestion.

```
<?php

class AdformAPI {

    private $baseUrl = 'https://api.example.com/Services';

    private $loginUrl = '/Security/Login';

    private $getDataExportUrl = '/DataExport/DataExportResult?DataExportName=ApiTest';

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $url = $this->baseUrl . $this->loginUrl;
        $params = json_encode(array('UserName' => $username, 'Password' => $password));
        $response = $this->_makePOSTRequest($url, $params);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        if (empty($response['Ticket'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid response');
        }

       // var_dump($response);
        return $response['Ticket'];
    }

    public function getExportData($ticket) {
        $url = $this->baseUrl . $this->getDataExportUrl;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Ticket: '. $ticket
        ));

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        return $output;
    }

    public function downloadFileFromUrl($url, $savePath) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
        $data = curl_exec ($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

//        if (!is_dir($savePath) && is_writable($savePath)) {
            $file = fopen($savePath, "w+");
            fputs($file, $data);
            fclose($file);
//        } else {
//            throw new \Exception('Unable to save file');
//        }
    }

    private function _makePOSTRequest($url, $json_data) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($json_data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $output;
    }
}

// Login and data download url
$api = new AdformAPI();
$ticket = $api->login('example', '123546');
$exportDataResponseJson = $api->getExportData($ticket);
$exportDataResponse = json_decode($exportDataResponseJson, true);

if (empty($exportDataResponse['DataExportResult']) || $exportDataResponse['DataExportResult']['DataExportStatus'] != "Done") {
    throw new \Exception('GetDataExport invalid response');
}

// Download zip
$fileDir = '/var/www/html/app-catalogue/web/export';
$fileName = 'report.zip';
$filePath = $fileDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
$api->downloadFileFromUrl($exportDataResponse['DataExportResult']['DataExportResultUrl'], $filePath);

// Unzip
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filePath);
$csvFilename = '';
if ($res === true) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $csvFilename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    }
    $zip->extractTo($fileDir);
    $zip->close();
} else {
    throw new Exception("Unable to unzip file");
}

// Parse CSV
$csvPath = $fileDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $csvFilename;

if (is_readable($csvPath)) {
    $dataCsv = file_get_contents($fileDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $csvFilename);
    $dataArr = explode("\n", $dataCsv);
    $dataPacked = array();

    foreach ($dataArr as $row) {
        $row = str_replace(" ", "", $row);
        //$row = wordwrap($row, 20, "\n", true);
        $row = preg_replace('/^.{20,}?\b/s', "$0&nbsp", $row);
        $row = explode("\t", $row);
        $dataPacked[] = $row;
    }
}



// SQL Connestion

$servername = "192.168.240.22";
$username = "liferaypublic";
$password = "liferaypublic";
$dbname = "liferay_dev";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$conn->query("set names 'utf8'");
$sql = " INSERT INTO ho_adform_reports (`Timestamp`, `Campaign`, `Paid_Keywords`, `Natural_Search_Keywords`, `Referrer_Type`, `Referrer`, `Page`, `Order_ID`)
VALUES ";

$flag = true;

foreach($dataPacked as $rowArray) {
    if($flag or count($rowArray)<= 7) { $flag = false; continue; }
    $sql .= "('".implode("','", $rowArray)."'),";
}
$sql = trim($sql,",");

echo $sql; //For debug only

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

//var_dump($dataPacked);
```

Comment: at first i would format the code in a nice way. isn't it horrible to look at such a bad formatted code for you as well? next thing that comes to my mind: what do all these ``enter code here`` mean - and do you really still have them in your actual code?

Comment: where is $conn build and why you querying before loop with uses it

Comment: why are you calling mysql_query($sql) three quarters of the way down.  The calling $conn->query($sql) after you remove the trailing ,\n??

Comment: What is the structure of `dataPacked`? What is the type of data being inserted in the database?
I don't see escaping on the strings (ex: addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string). Maybe there are single quotes messing up the sql statement.
More info.

Comment: @l0ckm4 is right. remove the trailing new line and comma is being done after the query execution.

Comment: @low_rents no that enter code here accidently left from a stackoverflow when I try to put code in my question. Sry this is my first question here.

Comment: @Adon except ID and Timestamp everything else is varchar. here is the example what I'm getting in one row ('2015-05-21&nbsp00:49:11','Hyperoptic-Tracking','','','ReferringSite','hyperoptic.com','A13:BBSub.Confirmation','26499
'),('2015-05-21&nbsp00:49:11','Hyperoptic-Tracking','','','ReferringSite','hyperoptic.com','A13:BBSub.Confirmation','26499
'),

Comment: Basically you will need one of these function for character varchar/text fields specifically.
Is the string you pasted here a direct copy? What is &nbsp; doing there. If the first column is of type datetime and not varchar, the query will fail.

Comment: @Adon yea it's direct copy a put name space there because it's separated with time and I use $row = preg_replace('/^.{20,}?\b/s', "$0&nbsp", $row); to put that name space. And the table expect data and time in that field.

Comment: Please then edit this post and paste the result of describe query for the table you are using (so we can see the fields and the types) and paste also the final resulting query.

Comment: @l0ckm4 find right solution he posted in Answer below. Thanks a lot l0ckm4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - I am assuming you have sanitised the values in $dataPacked.

Note edited to addslashes just in case.

```
$conn->query("set names 'utf8'");
$sql = " INSERT INTO ho_adform_reports (`Timestamp`, `Campaign`, `Paid_Keywords`, `Natural_Search_Keywords`, `Referrer_Type`, `Referrer`, `Page`, `Order_ID`)
VALUES ";

$flag = true;

foreach($dataPacked as $rowArray) {

    if($flag or count($rowArray)<= 7) { $flag = false; continue;}
    foreach ($rowArray as $k=>$v) {
         $sanitised = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/ui", '', $v);
         $rowArray[$k] = addslashes(trim($sanitised));
    }
    $sql .= "('".implode("','", $rowArray)."'),";
}
$sql = trim($sql,",");

echo $sql; //For debug only

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Example if file have 100 rows Im getting 100 rows in database but without a data

Comment: Did you try what I wrote or are you trying to explain a little more?  As I said in my comment to your question you are mixing mysql calls and in the wrong place.  It is no wonder things are going wrong.  I have tried to simplify and order your code for you.

Comment: @Milos Markovic I did not say I did not believe you but please try or tell me you have tried what I have suggested.  It would also be helpfull to see your $dataPacked array.  A few entries should be sufficient.

Comment: yap I check here is what i get when I var dump $dataPacked http://oi59.tinypic.com/259wg1k.jpg, My database is utf-8 and this is ASCII file maybe that's the problem. I edited a question and post whole script you can see whole code

Comment: I have made a small edit to the foreach to try to remove any non alpha numeric characters.  try that and see if it works.  Oh and get rid of the $0&nbsp weird thing and simply use a space ' '

Comment: Success THANK YOU VERY MUCK everything is o.k except date but doesnt meather I will check what's happening with that.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you enough.  Otherwise I will try to help more.

Comment: $row = preg_replace('/^.{20,}?\b/s', "$0&nbsp", $row); change to $row = preg_replace('/^.{20,}?\b/s', " ", $row);